# Why is the node_modules folder blacked out in Webstorm?

Tags: settings, webstorm

I'm using Webstorm to develop a web app.

However, in the projects bar, the `node_modules` folder is always blacked out and I don't want it to be (all the subfolders also get blacked-out when expanded).

I can't find any settings anywhere that point to this issue.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to turn it off?

[image: Webstorm Black Dark Line Projects]

Comment: please check if you have any custom colors defined in Settings/Appearance & Behaviour/File Colours/Local colours. If you don't, try invalidating caches (File/Invalidate caches, Restart) - does it help?

Comment: @lena I don't see anything of use there

Comment: try invalidating caches then

Comment: @lena Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: see my previous comment: File/Invalidate caches, Restart

Comment: Also post screenshot of your `Settings | Appearance & Behaviour | File Colours`. Disabling `Use in Project View` should help regardless of other settings.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `.gitignore` file, maybe `node_modules` listed there.

`.gitignore` file lists all files and folders (from your current project) that are excluded from version control (like Git).

Usually IDEs (like: Visual Studio Code, Webstorm, etc.) treat folders (excluded from version control) and their subfolders by changing its visual appearance (graying/blacking them out).

[More about .gitgnore.](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)